FastAI KeyError: "Label '755' was not included in the training dataset"
I am working on a quite simplified vision_learner model from FastAI that uses a resnet34 as backbone. It should classify mushroom images, and all the data loading parts are done correctly, except when I get to split between training and testing datasets.
It seems like something goes wrong there, and when I get to fitting the model, it churns out this error message:
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastai/data/transforms.py:263, in Categorize.encodes(self, o)
    261     return TensorCategory(self.vocab.o2i[o])
    262 except KeyError as e:
--> 263     raise KeyError(f"Label '{o}' was not included in the training dataset") from e

KeyError: "Label '755' was not included in the training dataset"

For context, this is how I load the data initially:
bs = 64
path = Path("../input/mushrooms/Mushrooms/")
fnames = []
for fpath in class_names:
    print(path/f'{fpath}/')
    fnames += get_image_files(path/f'{fpath}/')
....
../input/mushrooms/Mushrooms/Entoloma
../input/mushrooms/Mushrooms/Suillus
../input/mushrooms/Mushrooms/Hygrocybe
../input/mushrooms/Mushrooms/Agaricus
../input/mushrooms/Mushrooms/Amanita
../input/mushrooms/Mushrooms/Lactarius
../input/mushrooms/Mushrooms/Russula
../input/mushrooms/Mushrooms/Boletus
../input/mushrooms/Mushrooms/Cortinarius

And how I prepare it for the model:
np.random.seed(2)
pat = r"(\d+)_([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)\.jpg$"

item_tfms = Resize(224)  # Resizing each image to 224x224
batch_tfms = [*aug_transforms(), Normalize.from_stats(*imagenet_stats)]  # Standard augmentations + normalization

data = ImageDataLoaders.from_name_re(
    path='.', 
    fnames=fnames,
    pat=pat,
    item_tfms=item_tfms,
    batch_tfms=batch_tfms,
    bs=bs,
    num_workers=0 
)

train_dataset, test_dataset = data.train, data.valid
data.show_batch()

# Check classes
print(f"Number of classes: {len(data.vocab)}") # 2046

# Check datasets
print(f"Training dataset size: {len(data.train_ds)}") # 5372
print(f"Validation dataset size: {len(data.valid_ds)}") # 1342

And then I prepare the model
learn = vision_learner(data, models.resnet50, metrics=error_rate, lr=0.001)
learn.fit(n_epochs = 5, start_epoch=0)

Which ultimately leads to the issue above. Does someone have any hints as to what I'm doing wrong?

I decided to tackle this from another perspective, and it worked.
I used a DataBlock class from the fastai library directly, which allowed me to specify the actions I wanted to take on the data by myself.
dblock = DataBlock(
    blocks=(ImageBlock, CategoryBlock),
    get_items=get_image_files,
    splitter=RandomSplitter(valid_pct=0.2, seed=42),
    get_y=parent_label,
    item_tfms=Resize(224),
    batch_tfms=aug_transforms()
)

dls = dblock.dataloaders(path, bs=64)

learn = vision_learner(dls, resnet34, lr=0.005, metrics=accuracy)

This resulted in a correct handling of the training and testing sets.

You can simply remove the label if it's not supposed to exist in your dataset, or you can lower the learning rate.

Perhaps it would be helpful to include some sample code to show this

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
